# Why is the class not releasing – i.e., destructor is not getting called?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xamarin

I am creating an OSX, Mac project. I have a subclass `NSWindowController` seeing a memory leak. I am seeing it at two places:

1. When I use `OkButton.Activated += OKClicked`.

   I unregister it in `WillClose` as `OkButton.Activated -= OKClicked` but to no benefit.

   *I checked with an empty method. Still, the leak is seen.*
2. The call to `WhenActivated`, even though it is empty – i.e., has no binding inside it – even then the class is not releasing.

   ```
   this.WhenActivated(disposables => {});
   ```

What am I missing here? Why doesn’t this allow the holder class to get released?

Comment: Skip using the Xamarin auto-generated delegate for actions to eventhandlers and directly use `NSButton.CreateButton` supplying an Action (or create/add a selector to an an existing storyboard button via `NSButton.Action`, keep a ref to the selector and dispose if it when needed)

Comment: @SushiHangover: I tried that, now I am seen another funny thing. As soon as the window gets loaded it gets dealloc-ed. Leaving the buttons for no use. Xamarin is making me mad.

Comment: Not sure I understand, what is being `dealloc-ed`?

Comment: @SushiHangover: The class got released, the destructor got called.

Comment: Your NSWindowController subclass gets destructed? Where is it derived from, xib/storyboard or are you manually instancing it? (Maintaining a ref to it at the appdelegate level?)

Comment: Using Xib, manually instantiating the WindowController (that is actually a subclass of my own ReactiveWindowController) on click of an action on other window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182607/discussion-between-anoop-vaidya-and-sushihangover).